# How to delete multiple record in many to many relationship in spring Jpa data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, many-to-many

How to delete multiple record in many to many relationship in spring Jpa data.

```
Userid| transitioned 
 1    |      a
 1    |      b
 2    |      a
 2    |      b
 1    |      c  
 1    |      d
```

I have many to many relation database which I need to delete based on the request passed from client.

My payload will be like this. :

```
{
    userid : 1,
    transaction : [b,c]
}
```

I am following this example :
https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-many-to-many-mapping-example/

Before that

This is how I have used in my transaction DTO :

```
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "transiction_user",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "transaction_”id, referencedColumnName = "transaction_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")})
private Set<User> assignedUsers;
```

And in User DTO

```
@JsonIgnore
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "assignedUsers", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Transiction> transaction;
```

Now I have controller class for transiction with all my rest points, where I do all the operation.

Now I have to remove few records, with the payload.

As you can see my paylod have one userID and then transaction id in array. I will remove all the transaction from my intermediate table `transiction_user` w.r.t userid.

Can anybody help me to write controller and respective service implementation for that.

Comment: Would be great to get more detailed information about the delete process. From what I figured out the behaviour is like this: `UserId` and `transitioned` is sent. You look up the `user` in the db and remove the `transitioned` if I am correct?

Comment: @Nico yes you are write, I have updated the question.

Comment: Tried fetching user (1) from repository with transactions (a,b,c,d) then remove required transactions (b,c) from fetched associated collection of transactions and then persist/save?

Comment: I am not able to prepare my controller class only. getting 500. @SaurabhSingh